# Attempting to force download via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, download, fopen, readfile

I have a PDF file stored in the uploads directory of a Wordpress stack.  I am attempting to force the browser to download the PDF via AJAX.

```
    function get_pdf(){
    
      $file_path = realpath(WP_CONTENT_DIR).'/uploads/pdfs/12345.pdf';
    
        if (file_exists($file_path)) {
      
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_path).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));
            readfile($file_path, true);
                    
            exit;
           
        }
    
    }
```

When I run this function nothing happens.  I have also attempted this approach for triggering the download:

```
    if (file_exists($file_path)) {


      $handle = fopen($file_path, 'rb');
      $buffer = '';

      while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, 4096);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
      }

      fclose($handle);
        

    }
```

Any suggestions on how I can debug this to get it to work?

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` — The Content-Type for a PDF file is `application/pdf`. You shouldn't say its just some bytes if you know better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a browser **navigates** to a URL the response will either be displayed inline (i.e. in the browser window) or saved.  Which of these happens is determined by a combination of the file type and the `Content-Disposition` header.

When a browser requests data using Ajax the response **will be handled by the JavaScript that made the request**.

There is no way for a response header (or anything else about the response) to make that JavaScript save the file instead of passing it to JavaScript for handling.

The JavaScript **could** be written to pay attention to the `Content-Disposition` header but, generally speaking, the author of the JS won't need to use a header like that to decide what to do with the file.